# ASP.NET GridView binding sequence

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, data-binding

I'm trying to bind my GridView at runtime, but I'm also trying to avoid running all the binding events twice.

I have a GridView that gets populated from a function that returns a DataTable. I'm not using ViewState in the grid for a couple of reasons. I seem to have a Catch-22 situation here:

- If I don't bind the grid by Page_Load at the latest, the RowCommand and other grid events won't fire.
- If I DO bind the grid in Page_Load, but I'm on a PostBack from a pager link, sort link, or search button, those event handlers will change the data and need to rebind it, running all the binding code again.

The grid triggers DataBound, RowDataBound, and RowCreated events, which *could* be performing expensive operations. I really hate to call them all in Page_Load, and then wipe out the data and call them all again if the data changes. But I can't seem to avoid this double duty, because in Page_Load I don't know if it was a grid event that will change the data, or a grid event that doesn't.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the command arguments. If a button in the gridview was clicked, that event will be fired and you can handle it appropriately. Your question is not clear enough i'm afraid. Could you be more specific?

Comment: I added the two scenarios in an EDIT. I like the command arguments idea though, I'll look into that.

Comment: The command arguments did it for me. I had to make the action columns ITemplate columns, and add HtmlAnchor controls to them. This let me override the href property and set it to javascript:__doPostBack('commandName', 'commandArg'), which I can then decode in Page_Load. Seems roundabout, but it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check if request is a postback. Bind the datatable to the grid like so:

If(!ispostback)...
That way you wont be binding the table to the grid on each request.

Comment: The problem is IsPostBack isn't specific enough. I need to know if it was a postback from a button in the grid (and therefore will generate a RowCommand event), or not.

Comment: Scenario 1) why would you want to handle the binding in page_load? You are changing the content u want to operate on. What exactly are u trying to accomplish, that way i can solve ur problem. You can bind the grid to the table in the onclick event of the commqnd button in the grid...

Comment: I think u shud really try if(!ispostback) then do the initial binding, else do nothing and the appflow will take u to the event that caused a postback. Read an article on asp.net page lifecycle

Comment: Sorry, I know this could be a lot clearer. In scenario 1, I don't change the visible data. This would be like a detail button in a grid, it needs to generate a RowCommand event, but then it does something different.

Comment: Are you using the debugger? Just set a breakpoint in page_load and in every other handler ur interested in, run the app (f5) and step through your code pressing f10. That way u'll monitor what parts of your code execute. Cheers mate

Comment: Yes, i'm debugging. I changed the scenarios in the description to make it more clear. Basically I just don't want all the databinder events to fire twice, but both scenarios are postbacks, so I can't find a way to differentiate.